# Ionic Serve Command gives an error

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am Devolping a mobile application using ionic framework.
When I run the command ionic server, the it throws this error:

```
/deps/uv/src/unix/stream.c:494: uv__server_io: Assertion `events == 1' failed
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an error with your Node. Try the following commands first to see if your errors get solved:

```
sudo npm install npm -g
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install node -g
```

This will update your NPM (Node.js' package manager) if not already updated.

If that won't work, I'd recommend a re-install:

```
sudo npm uninstall node
sudo apt-get purge npm
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm install node -g
```

Let me know if you face issues in the process.